# SaltSatck: Apache-formula modules errors

Tags: apache, module, salt-stack

I'm working on updating my **apache formula** but I have some errors while the executing of the commande

> salt myminion state.highstate

I think that it's about **the apache modules**

This is what I have got as a result :

```
      ID: a2enmod fastcgi
Function: cmd.run
  Result: False
 Comment: One or more requisite failed: apache.mod_fastcgi.mod-fastcgi
 Started: 
Duration: 
 Changes:   
  ----------
      ID: a2enmod fcgid
Function: cmd.run
  Result: True
 Comment: unless execution succeeded
 Started: 18:42:48.946972
Duration: 14.365 ms
 Changes:   
  ----------
      ID: a2enmod perl2
Function: cmd.run
  Result: False
 Comment: Command "a2enmod perl2" run
 Started: 18:42:48.964446
Duration: 52.189 ms
 Changes:   
          ----------
          pid:
              13892
          retcode:
              1
          stderr:
              ERROR: Module perl2 does not exist!
          stdout:

      ID: apache-restart
Function: module.wait
    Name: service.restart
  Result: False
 Comment: One or more requisite failed: apache.mod_fastcgi.a2enmod fastcgi, apache.mod_perl2.a2enmod perl2
 Started: 
Duration: 
 Changes:
```

Can anyone give me some help to resolve those issues,
Thank you.
B.Marouane

Comment: Could you please paste the full output of your salt run? I think the first error `Comment: One or more requisite failed: apache.mod_fastcgi.mod-fastcgi` indicates that something is failing before this state is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The output is very descriptive.

This command:

> Command "a2enmod perl2" run

Throws that error:

> ERROR: Module perl2 does not exist!

Make sure that this apache module is installed on your minion. Post your pillar data, if you need further assistance.

Depending on your target OS the formula might lack proper support. Read [this source](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula/blob/master/apache/mod_perl2.sls) for further troubleshouting and understanding.